# Can the migration path from SO be reconsidered?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, migration

We've had [some discussion recently](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1899/the-business-of-being-a-migration-path-for-stack-overflow) about bad Programmers questions being migrated from Stackoverflow. The number of close votes required to migrate on SO was changed from 3/5 to 4/5 in response.

However, I'm not sure if that has made a difference. It seems to me that a lot of the migrated question get closed quickly. Unfortunately I don't have 10k yet so I can't see the actual stats.

Could we have another look at the closing statistics on migrated questions from SO? If there's not been a significant reduction in that rate, I suggest that the path be removed. If there are questions that belong here (and I know there are quite a few) they can be flagged and migrated by a moderator.

Answer (score 10):

The migration stats tell us that over the last 90 days, 790 questions were migrated from Stack Overflow to Programmers and 26% of those (~205 questions) were "rejected". If memory serves, a migration is "rejected" when the migrated question is closed or deleted.

So we have a quarter (give or take) of the questions migrated to us that get closed.

My perception is that that number is lower than it should be. With 790 questions migrated in, I think more than a few just never got noticed and didn't get closed. I didn't go hunting through questions, though, to see if that's really the case.

I think it's fairly rare for us to see a good, on-topic questions migrated from Stack Overflow, so I definitely support reviewing whether its worth keeping the migration path or not.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with "it's fairly rare for us to see good, on-topic questions migrated from SO.."

Comment: Is that a diamond mod tool to see these stats? I'm interested in the rejected numbers for an arbitrary site X to arbitrary site Y. I wonder if it would support the hypothesis that the migration system is somewhat broken due to a lack of understanding about what a community is willing to accept.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure if it's mod-only or 10k+. The only stats available to us here are for migrations from other sites to Programmers. For "arbitrary X to arbitrary Y" stats we'd have to ask an employee for stats or mods on site Y.

Comment: It's available to me on SO with 25k rep. I'll find out in a couple of weeks if it's a 10k tool, given my current trend on Programmers.

Comment: The migration stats are available to 10K+ users.